# Having issues changing values in a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I am trying to take items.unit_price, increase it's value by 10% inside a subquery and then display it in another column.

Here is my code

```
select items.title, items.unit_price, items.unit_price as Price_increase
from artists
join items
on items.artist_id = artists.artist_id
order by price_increase in
(
    select distinct round(items.unit_price + (items.unit_price * 0.1), 2) as Price_increase
    from artists
    where artists.artist_name = "No Rest For The Weary"
)
;
```

Comment: Your title is completely nonsense, fix it and I remove my downvote.

Comment: Yes, I've changed my downvote to up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select i.title, i.unit_price,
       (case when a.artist_name = 'No Rest For The Weary'
             then 1.1*i.unit_price else i.unit_price
        end) as Price_increase
from artists a join
     items i
     on i.artist_id = a.artist_id
order by price_increase;
```

Comment: I'm supposed to be using a subquery. Is what you posted considered a subquery? Because I really don't know.

Comment: *I'm supposed to be using a subquery*...is this a homework problem?

Comment: It was for a project, I think I more or less figured out what the issue was.